# Php check exact date and time with holiday listing based on weekends

Tags: php, date

Scenario :- I have a list of holidays but the date themselves don't know weather they are week days or week ends. Based on the calculation of date time with holiday listing and weekend/weekdays.

I have to make a list of calculations based on date and time and holidays added by the user dynamically, and each week day does not have any fixed working hours so removing a fixed hour from a date is not possible.

Also the dates are suppose to be calculated based on the year. So if a date in a year is weekday the date will be included and if another year has the same date as weekend the date will be excluded.

Date calculation based on the year and week ends/week days will be smarter.

PHP will be preferred.

Comment: Sounds amazing! Good luck with the code and post again if you have a specific issue with a specific code example.

Comment: You want to see a code snippet?

Comment: At least logic will be preferred.

Comment: The question is currently a requirements specification. Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: No need of any code i will do it by myself. But any idea on this. I have made the whole crud functionality but stuck with the logic. Not sure how do i proceed. Also I am doing it for free in an open source app.

Comment: [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Best of luck!

Comment: Is there anything that returns what day is exactly that date is? eg:- sun, mon, tue, etc.

Comment: [DateTime::format('w')](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Thanks that's it. My work is done here.

Comment: You can add this to answer. and i will rate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123599/discussion-between-sujit-prasad-and-jedifans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the question is about how to find out if a given date on a weekend.

The 'w' formatting flag can be used to determine the day of the week of a given date, which can be checked against 0 or 6 which indicate Sunday or Saturday.

See  [DateTime::format('w')](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and be sure to click through to the `date()` format description see what else can be used!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.